# SLURM: After allocating all GPUs no more cpu job can be submitted

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gpu, nvidia, slurm

We have just started using slurm for managing our GPUs (currently just 2). We use ubuntu 14.04 and slurm-llnl. ​I have configured gres.conf and `srun` works. 
The problem is that if I run two jobs with `--gres=gpu:1` then the two GPUs are successfully allocated and the jobs start running; now I expect to be able to run more jobs (in addition to the 2 GPU jobs) without `--gres=gpu:1` (i.e. jobs than only use CPU and ram) but it is not possible.

The error message says that it could not allocate required resources (even though there are 24 CPU cores).

This is my gres.conf:

```
Name=gpu Type=titanx File=/dev/nvidia0
Name=gpu Type=titanx File=/dev/nvidia1
NodeName=ubuntu Name=gpu Type=titanx File=/dev/nvidia[0-1]
```

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: have you tried what happes if you specify cpus in the gres conf and leave some over for the use of other allocations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `SelectType` in your configuration is `CR_CPU` or `CR_Core` and that the `shared` option of the partition is not set to `exclusive`. Otherwise Slurm allocates full nodes to jobs.