# SLURM overcommiting GPU

Tags: gpu, slurm

How can one run multiple jobs in parallel on one GPU? One option which works is to run a script that spawn child processes. But is there also a way to do it with SLURM itself? I tried

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:1
#SBATCH --overcommit
srun python script1.py & 
srun python script2.py &
wait
```

But that still runs them sequentially.

**EDIT:** We still want to allocate recourses exlusively, i.e. one SBATCH job should allocate a whole GPU for itself. The question is whether there is an easy way to start multiple scripts within the SBATCH in parallel, without having to setup a multiprocessing environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SLURM: After allocating all GPUs no more cpu job can be submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093705/slurm-after-allocating-all-gpus-no-more-cpu-job-can-be-submitted)